# Output from a TV to a 2nd monitor

Tags: output, monitors

I do AV work at our church. We have a stage TV monitor that sits outside of and above the sound booth where it can be seen from the stage, but not from the booth.

I'd like to output from the TV to a small LCD monitor inside the sound booth so I can monitor exactly what they're seeing from the stage. I do *not* want to output from the video switcher to a 2nd monitor inside the booth, I want the output from that screen going to a daisy-chained monitor that I can see.

There are 2 reasons for wanting to do it this way:

1. The IR repeater that we're using for this monitor isn't quite as reliable as I'd like it to be. With a secondary monitor daisy-chained from it, I can turn on the "inside" monitor and, when I see an image on it, I'll know the "outside" monitor is on.
2. Should I ever happen to hit the wrong button on the video switcher (like I did this morning), a quick glance at this "inside" monitor will help me resolve why there are panicked looks on the faces of the musicians on stage.

I've got a old, small LCD monitor that I don't use for anything. It's only got a VGA input, but I don't mind picking up a component-to- or HDMI-to-VGA converter to use it, but I need to be able to grab the signal from that stage monitor so I know what's going on.

I realize that I could put an HDMI splitter on the cable leading to the TV to resolve issue #2, but that won't tell me if the TV is on/off which I need to resolve issue #1.

Do TVs generally have a video out that could be used for this? Since this was purchased on a church budget, it's probably not a super high-end TV. I haven't had a chance to get up on a ladder and look for a model number, and I forgot to check what brand it is. If it doesn't have a video out, what other options might I have to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I have not ever heard of a TV that has this feature (I have encountered a few).  Some high-end monitors have this, it's called [Display Port daisy-chaining](https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/).  As the name implies, it uses DisplayPort and not HDMI.  It's quite a hack; but, I think that your cheapest option would be to put a camera outside the booth looking back at the screen.  Amazon has some very good deals on decent performing cameras, look at Dericam.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I wanted to hear... I'm working on a better  IR extender solution that should eliminate the "is it on?" question and will go with a simple HDMI splitter to ensure I'm outputting the right info.